# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 while compiling groovy script with ANT

Tags: java, ant, groovy

I have a groovy script which I am trying (for the first time) to compile and run using the ant build.xml file. It throws a

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
```

I searched for it and the results have suggested that it may be a cause of the version mismatch. Well I have java 1.6.0_35 and ANT version 1.8.1. What can be the reason for the error?. Please help.

Comment: Which version of groovy was this with?

Comment: This is with the latest groovy 2.2 release Tim.

Comment: What version of the Jar were you using?  I assume it was the `groovy-all-2.2.0-indy.jar` one?  This is a special Java 7 build, I've just checked `embeddable/groovy-all-2.2.0.jar` and `embeddable/groovy-all-2.2.1.jar` and both have Java 5 as their class version in `org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case might be is that you are compiling it with the installed JDK 7. And to run it uses JRE 6 which is on your system path.

You can check the versions with commands:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

**UPDATE**

It's the Groovyc itself which requires JDK 7. You could try running one of earlier Groovy releases or to upgrade your JDK.

Comment: both java -version and javac -version are 1.6.0_35

Comment: Version 51 stands for JDK 7. So it somehow sneaks into the compilation process. My guesses: you have old files which are not updated during compilation OR you could output the `javac` version from the ant script (with `<exec>`) OR your ANT script somehow finds where JDK7 is installed to - i.e. there is `JAVA_HOME` environment variable which points to JDK7

Comment: my `JAVA_HOME` variable is C:\Java\jdk-6u35-x64. Actually the error is thrown at this line in the build.xml file `classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc` while the error shown in the terminal is `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/codehaus/groovy/ant/Groovyc`. Does this help?

Comment: Did you try specifying the target for your compilation: `<javac source="1.6" target="1.6" debug="on" />`?

Comment: Ah, seems I got it. It's the Groovyc itself which requires JDK 7. You could try running one of earlier Groovy releases or to upgrade your JDK.

Comment: Nope.I am actually trying out this example from a book and I dont see a target specification like the one you mentioned. The target is like this `<target name="run" depends="complie"
  description="run the compiled class">
  <java classname="fibonacci">
   <classpath refid="groovy.classpath"/>
   <classpath location="classes"/>
  </java>  
 </target>`

Comment: Doc on target: http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovyc+Ant+Task. I'm thinking, that it's the `org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc` which is compiled with JDK7, so you could try downloading an earlier version.

Comment: Yeah sure I ll try that, but just so that you know, I haven't encountered this problem when I ran the same groovy script using `java` keyword.

Comment: Ok. I see. I think I've run out of guesses. I will definitely update to the latest JDK when I notice this weirdness...

Comment: I installed a previous version of groovy and it ran. You were right! Either we need to have the JDK7 for the latest groovy or an older groovy version for the JDK6. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc` Should not require Java 7, it should require Java 5.

Indeed, I just checked `groovy-all-2.2.0.jar`, `groovy-all-2.2.1.jar`, `groovy-ant-2.2.0.jar` and `groovy-ant-2.2.1.jar` with `javap` and they all showed:

```
$ javap -verbose org/codehaus/groovy/ant/Groovyc.class 
Classfile org/codehaus/groovy/ant/Groovyc.class
  Last modified 18-Nov-2013; size 26620 bytes
  MD5 checksum 6d629004a728203e26a1671626cf3dab
  Compiled from "Groovyc.java"
public class org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc extends org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MatchingTask
  SourceFile: "Groovyc.java"
  InnerClasses:
       #306; //class org/codehaus/groovy/ant/Groovyc$1
       public static #488= #114 of #698; //Entry=class java/util/Map$Entry of class java/util/Map
  minor version: 0
  major version: 49
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
```

`major version: 49` is Java 5.

The only caveat to this is if you use the `indy` jars.  These are builds for Java 7 that use the [new `InvokeDynamic` support](http://groovy.codehaus.org/InvokeDynamic+support)

So, as a general rule, you should use `groovy-ant-2.2.1.jar` or the complete `groovy-all-2.2.1.jar` (which both will work with Java 5+)